# Slideshows with thumbnails and colorbox

Tags: javascript

So here's what i would like to achieve:

[image: slideshow with thumbnails and colorbox]

The "big image" acts like a slideshow. It doesn't need to automatically display the next images.

The red squares are thumbnails from the slideshow.

What I want to do is, when we hover a thumbnail, the "big image" displays it, and when we click on a thumbnail, it opens a colorbox.

I've made lots of researches, but didn't find out how to integrate colorbox with this. So is this possible, and if yes, what would be the easiest solution? (I'm not yet used with theme's template modfying, module creation, functions overriding, but could handle it if well explained :P)

Thank you !